# Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (Mysql and Foreign key)

Tags: php, mysql, database, foreign-key-relationship

When I trying to run the code, this error shows up

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
>   (`hotel_info`.`results`, CONSTRAINT `results_ibfk_5` FOREIGN KEY
>   (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES `customer` (`CustomerID`) ON DELETE CASCADE
>   ON UPDATE CASCADE)

Here is the code

```
$result = mysql_query("select customer.CustomerID from customer inner join results on customer.CustomerID = results.CustomerID where customer.Username = '".$aid."'");
            if (false === $result) 
            {
                echo     mysql_error();
            }

if (isset($_POST["submitbtn"]))
{
    $LP = $_POST["LP"];
    $budget = $_POST["budget"];
    $checkin = $_POST["CheckIn"];
    $checkout = $_POST["CheckOut"];
    $unit = $_POST["unit"];
    $smokep = $_POST["SmokeP"];
    $spreq = $_POST["sp_req"];


        if($checkin>$checkout)
        {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("End Date must greater than Start Date.");
        </script>           

        <?php
        }
        else
        {
            $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO results(`LP`, `budget`, `CheckIn`, `CheckOut`, `unit`, `SmokeP`, `sp_req`, `CustomerID`) values ('$LP', '$budget', 
                                        '$checkin', '$checkout', '$unit', '$smokep', '$spreq', '$result')");    

            if (false === $query) 
            {
                echo     mysql_error();
            }

            echo "Reservation form has been submitted!<br>
                <a href=view.php>view all</a>";

        }
}
```

Here is the sql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `results` (
  `BookID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `LP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `budget` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckIn` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CheckOut` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `unit` int(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `SmokeP` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sp_req` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CustomerID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`BookID`),
  KEY `Username` (`CustomerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=48 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `customer` (
  `CustomerID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Username` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `ContactNo` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

I've already stuck for two days because of this error, please help.

Comment: I'm just curious, does that insert statement even contain values? You have single quotes around PHP variables...

Comment: @JJ___ Missing `$id` value in your code, and you are passing that value in your query.

Comment: mysql_ functions are deprecated, and HAVE BEEN REMOVED in PHP 7. Please, stop using them AT ONCE, not even for exercise.

Comment: I'm so sorry, it was a mistake, I've edit the code.

Comment: Tomanow, yea previously the values were able to insert to database. But once I added a foreign key entity then everything is different now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from the error it is clear that foreign key constraint fails. Please check your **customer** table which must have **CustomerID** that you are trying to insert in **results** table insert query i.e. check value of **$id**. have you assigned any value for **$id**

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO results(`LP`, `budget`, `CheckIn`, `CheckOut`, `unit`, `SmokeP`, `sp_req`, `CustomerID`) values ('$LP', '$budget', 
                                        '$checkin', '$checkout', '$unit', '$smokep', '$spreq', '$id')");    

In above query value for $id not set so first assign value to that.
```